# Laravel Factory not calling callback 'afterCreating'

Tags: php, laravel, model, factory

I'm trying to modify models after creating them with Factory. I have defined configure() method and within it what I want changed within the model. However, Laravel doesn't call it and it saves the original values which aren't modified. How to fix this?

Here is the configure function within the MealFactory:

```
public function configure()
{
    return $this->afterCreating(function (Meal $meal) {
        $meal->setTranslation('title', 'hr', 'Croatian translation' . $meal->getId())
            ->setTranslation('title', 'de', 'German translation' . $meal-getId());
    });
}
```

In table seeder I call it like this:

```
    $meals = $mealFactory
        ->count(15)
        ->create();
```

Answer (score 4):

According to https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Factories/Factory.php

method configure called only when method new called, which in current version called only when times is called, so in your case should work using:

```
$mealFactory
    ->times(15)
    ->create();
```

Comment: In my case `Model::factory()->create();`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Влад Киевский, `configure()` is only called from `new()`, so make sure you are using `new()` to instantiate the factory class.

```
// Don't use
$mealFactory = new MealFactory();

// Use instead
$mealFactory = MealFactory::new();
```

Comment: What? Aren't you supposed to use `Meal::factory->create()`? That is what Laravel uses all over the documentation.

Comment: @Pelmered The problem from the original post occurs when the factory is instantiated with the new keyword, so this solution is adapted to that circunstance. Ofcourse, you can also use the factory method from the HasFactory trait to instantiate the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Call `$meal->save()` at the end of `afterCreating` callback.

Consider following code;

```php
    return $this->afterCreating(function (Meal $meal) {
        $meal->setTranslation('title', 'hr', 'Croatian translation' . $meal->getId())
            ->setTranslation('title', 'de', 'German translation' . $meal-getId());

        // Save
        $meal->save();
    });
```

Comment: It seems you use `spatie/laravel-translatable` lib. Could you show me the full code of the factory and seeder?